# "not an answer" flag declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I have recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28442379/1987598) as not being an answer. I am sure it does not answer the question and is only a comment.

Since my first flag was declined I custom-flagged the post again, explaining that it is not an answer and that I disagree with the flag rejection. The second flag was declined with

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

But in my opinion, this post is not wrong, and neither is it technically inaccurate - it's just that it is only a comment, not an answer.

I would appreciate if somebody could point out to me where my reasoning is flawed.

Comment: Why is it not an answer?  It looks like a reasonable **attempt** to answer the question.  Moderators do not act based on correctness of an answer, so if the answer is just wrong, then that is not a flaggable offense.

Comment: @psubsee2003 As I said, the post is _correct_, _not_ wrong - but it does not answer the question. There must be a line between attempts to answer questions and comments - and I am asking where that line is.

Comment: But I think the issue is **why**.  Did you explain the why to the moderator when you flagged or just say "this doesn't answer the question" in your flag.  The mods are not subject matter experts in many cases, they rely on the users who flag to help them understand what action needs to be taken and why it needs to be taken.  In my experience, if your flag doesn't convince them that it needs to be deleted then they generally err on the side of keeping the post.

Comment: @Mathias, it is an attempt at answering, even though it misses the point. The current (quasi-)consensus is that attempts at answering are answers, even when misguided. On the other hand, something like *Look! The huge manatee!* would not be an answer.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Right, I can live with that - in this case, I have myself been misguided about comments disguised as answers, because if I understand you correctly, on-topic comments should always be tolerated if they are posted as an answer.

Comment: @Mathias, that depends on the comment. *You can't have a classname with spaces* would be better as a comment, yes, but as an answer it does attempt to provide a solution to the question. Comments like *Have you debugged that code? What does the console say?*, on the other hand, are acceptable as comments but not as answers.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks for your advice, I'll keep in mind that flags need conclusive explanations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Choosing to flag as *Not an Answer* can be a problem when the issue is not cut and dry.  Because there is no explanation possible (except by leaving a comment under the post) it will be declined more often than not, unless it is obvious why the post was flagged.  This also goes for answers that appear to answer the question.  The most successful "Not an answer" flags are the ones in which the answer is little more than gibberish, a thank you comment, a follow up question, or something completely unrelated to programming.

This is compounded by the fact that these flags go both to the community via the Low Quality Review Queue, and to the Moderators, so you will see inconsistent results depending on who responds to the flag.  In my experience, Moderators tend to be more forgiving than the community when evaluating posts, so you might have success flagging a single post like that as not an answer, but if you do it often, you will see mixed results.

When selecting an "Other" flag, explanation is a priority.  You might get lucky and your flag is seen by a moderator who is a subject matter expert (or at least has some experience) in the topic at hand.  If so, they will probably see the same thing you do and act accordingly.

However, more often than not, you are going to get a moderator who does not know the material well enough to evaluate, and in some obscure tags they might not have a clue.  As the flagger, you should take the time to lay out the situation for the moderator as briefly as you can.  Tell them what (exactly) is wrong with the post and why it does't conform to our guidelines.  You also should tell them what you expect them to do.  Do you want them to convert it to a comment?  Do you want them to delete the post?  Do you want them to do something else?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I agree that the explanation I gave was not enough - and it is indeed likely that the flag was declined because of that.

Comment: Yeah?  What about this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54528847/2890724, I flagged as being not an answer and the flag was declined.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda the answer is beyond horrible, but it still is an attempt to answer the question.  Downvote, and if you have the necessary privileges, vote to delete.  But it still doesn't qualify as "not an answer" since it is an *attempt* to answer (regardless of how poor of an attempt)

Comment: @psubsee  I think answers like that just add unneccessary and missleading content to SO. It should be removed. On the other hand, that was posted after the OP states in a comment that he was solved the issue just restarting. I see that as an attempt to earn a few rep points. Not an answer. Besides, if declining flags grant some type of reward or badge might be users trying to earn those too.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I have seen answers with more quality be removed on the same basis.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda as to why flags on better answers have been successful - remember that there is one (or more) of many different humans on the other side of that flag.  It depends on how that person perceives the post, and it is very possible that person is not familiar with the specific language.  It is well documented on meta that if it looks like an answer, then your flag has a  likelihood of being declined.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda and i don't disagree that posts like that are not good to keep around.  I'm just trying to explain how and why things are.  A "not an answer" flag is not appropriate for a very poor quality answer as that is not what that flag is designed to do.  Instead use the tools at your disposal.

Comment: @psubsee2003 so we agreed that humans at the other side of the flag "decide" if the post is an answer or not. But there is no way that "just restart your app, it will work"  qualify as an answer. It just not explain nothing. It is a very long shot gessing, it should be a comment.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda no, comments are not meant for half answers.  That post is a very bad answer, not a comment.  The "should be a comment" part of the flag description is very misleading.  I don't want to be rude because I mostly agree with your desire to remove crap, but please stop arguing your point.  I get it.  You want to flag bad content away, but the general consensus is the site doesn't work like that.  Bad content needs to be moderated via downvoting and delete votes (and close votes for questions).

Comment: @RaydelMiranda see [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) for more info.  This is the official guidance on how to use Not an Answer.

Comment: Man, you rock! I had a "Not an answer flag" declined, flagged again as "Other" following your advice, and it was found "helpful" just 8 mins after...!

Answer (score 5):

The answer can be read in two different ways.

> You can't have a classname with spaces. The spaces in `class=""` mean you have multiple classes.

can be read as either

> It doesn't matter for your current problem, but beware that you can't have a classname with spaces. The spaces in `class=""` mean you have multiple classes.

or

> The reason it is not working is that you can't have a classname with spaces. The spaces in `class=""` mean you have multiple classes.

The former is correct, but not an answer, so should be a comment.

The latter is incorrect, I think, but an attempt to directly address the question asked, and would be rightly posted as an answer.

To me personally, it comes across to me as the latter. To you, it seems to be more of the former. To whoever reviewed your flag, it presumably also came across as more of the latter.

There are no mind-readers here, so there's no telling who might be right. I would probably just leave a comment on the answer requesting clarification on the reason for posting it, and only deciding on what to do next after getting a response to that.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it was first, but both of you are raising valid points. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Louis Yes, you are certainly correct, but that has nothing to do with the question in this case. It's true that the OP is saying something which is technically inaccurate, but their problem is a different one.

Comment: @Louis I'm well aware of that. "The reason it is not working is that [...]" would nonetheless be incorrect because what follows is unrelated to why it is not working.

Comment: @Louis I never claimed otherwise. I gave two valid interpretations of the answer, and explained that the second is how I think it was meant to be read, but that I might be wrong about that.

Comment: I read it as the latter as well (I'm not one of the moderators that declined the flag, but would have, for the reasons you lay out).

Comment: @hvd I see what you mean now. Sorry about that.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I also agree with this answer. What can I do if, while being banned from flagging because of the above, I discover something that potentially is serious abuse and that I'd like to report?

Comment: @MathiasMüller Wait 6 days.